# Return outside function error is confusing me

Tags: python, return, syntax-error

I am new to python and i getting so mad at this one issue which i dont know how to solve and there seems to be no help on the internet which works. If you know what the issue is please help.

```
guesses = 0
usernum = int(input("pick a number betwen 1 and 10"))
if usernum > 10 or usernum < 1:
    print("That number is bigger than 10 or smaller than 1. Try again")
    usernum = int(input("pick a number betwen 1 and 10"))
    if usernum > 10 or usernum < 1:
        print("You failed... again. wow thats sad just restart the program")

print("okay now i will find what your number is...")

while not compnum == usernum:
    import random
    compnum = random.int(1, 10)
    guesses = gueses +1
    if not compnum == usernum:
        return
```

the error is

File "", line 16
return
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function

Comment: there's a typo on line 15 'gueses' should be 'guesses'. Also, a while loop cannot return anything, a function can return something. Are you wanting 'break' instead?

Comment: Your *return* statement isn't in a function

Comment: Thank you so much you for this I finally finished it. This was my first python project and am super grateful for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`return` must be used in a function. Like this:

```py
def fun():
    statements
    .
    .
    return [expression]
```

On line 14 you wrote `guesses = gueses +1`, `gueses`is not defined

Your code should look like this:

```py
import random # import a the top 

compnum = random.randint(1, 10) # generate number once

guesses = 0
usernum = int(input("pick a number betwen 1 and 10: "))
if usernum > 10 or usernum < 1:
    print("That number is bigger than 10 or smaller than 1. Try again: ")
    usernum = int(input("pick a number betwen 1 and 10: "))
    if usernum > 10 or usernum < 1:
        print("You failed... again. wow thats sad just restart the program: ")

print("okay now i will find what your number is...: ")

while not compnum == usernum:
    usernum = int(input("pick a number betwen 1 and 10: "))
    guesses = guesses +1
    if not compnum == usernum:
        continue
```

Comment: Continue with programming and ask your questions :)

Comment: Just some advice for your code: in the conditions for the if statements it would be more readable to do `not 1 < usernum < 10` instead of `usernum > 10 or usernum < 1` and, at the end, when you do `guesses = guesses+1` it'll be more clean if you use the `iadd` operator, `+=`.

Comment: @FabianHofstetter actually using your method it's about 4x slower and mostly confusing, here is the result: https://pastebin.com/UbRPxLdw

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use return outside of a function.
If you want to stop a loop, you need to use `break` or you make the whole a function. But in fact there is no need to use that if statement, the while loop will stop anyway. The following version of the code does what you want.

```
import random

def guess(number):
    guesses = 1
    compnum = random.randint(1, 10)
    while not compnum == usernum:
        compnum = random.randint(1, 10)
        guesses = guesses + 1
    return f"number: {compnum}", f"guesses: {guesses}"

usernum = int(input("pick a number betwen 1 and 10"))
if usernum > 10 or usernum < 1:
     print("That number is bigger than 10 or smaller than 1. Try again")
     usernum = int(input("pick a number betwen 1 and 10"))
     if usernum > 10 or usernum < 1:
         print("You failed... again. wow thats sad just restart the program")

print("okay now i will find what your number is...")
print(guess(usernum))
```